Arch Linux: Mixed themed settings: Trying to set Code-OSS Desktop Application's icon from its property window
First here's my current setup:
I have Arch Linux installed through VirtualBox on Windows 10 Pro. I'm using VirtualBox because I am only limited to WSL1 since my CPU does not have Hyper-V SLAT extension support.
The installation process went smoothly and during the stage of setting my partitions and partition types, the install script gave me the option to include different packages within the installation process.
Here I chose various Desktop Environments, Windows Managers, etc... Within this list I installed:
Cinnamon, KDE-Plasma, Xfce, among a few other things. I also included dev or code options, 32bit support, intel microcode, etc... I choose everything that was applicable to my system and features that I wanted to test out.
I'm also a bit new to Linux with limited experience. I'm not new to using computers it's just a matter of learning the internals of the Linux Kernel.
So far at this stage all of the installation processes went smoothly. Not important here, but just to demonstrate what I've been able to accomplish since this is my first rodeo with Arch Linux, I was able to successfully install notepad++. I first had to acquire snap and install that, and snap required me to install git. All of this was done through bash using pacman.   
This is just to give the reader some scope of my capabilities but also my limitations.

My current Desktop Environment I believe for right now is set to Cinnamon.
Here is my customization:

Under System Settings: Themes:

Mouse Pointer: Oxygen_Zion
Applications:  CBlack
Icons:         Enlightment-X
Desktop:       Adapta-Nokto



Here's what I'm trying to do:
I have vscode installed from the base repository. This is not the "MS-version". This is the open source Code-OSS version.
Now when I pinned this to the desktop it's showing a default icon that looks like a text file with indentation.
When I try to change this icon by right clicking on it, selecting properties, clicking on the already preset icon, it gives me a list of all of the visible icons to choose from in the "Choose Icon" window.
Here I think the Enlightment-X icon theme is what's being presented, and I've searched all through these folders, and could not find the icon I am looking for to use. I even used the search bar, and no luck. I used the browse window and can't seem to navigate or find the location of the icon I want to use.
Now if I close out all of those Windows and I open up Dolphin and navigate to:
/home/achilles/.local/share/applications/
Here it shows the application: code-oss.desktop. Within Dolphin, the icon it is using/displaying is the one I want to use for my desktop, menu bar, and panel bar(s).
I'm trying to navigate, find, locate to this icon's path, and I'm also trying to get my current active theme to use this icon.
When I open this code-oss.desktop file under the icon section:
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Code - OSS
Comment=Code Editing. Redefined.
GenericName=Text Editor
Exec=code-oss %F
Icon=com.visualstudio.code.oss

It appears to be set correctly. Now I'm just trying to find the path location of com.vistualstudio.code.oss and I'm trying to get Enlightment-X's icon theme to recognize this.
I can see this icon within Dolphin itself. Yet through Cinnamon itself which I believe is using Nemo... I cannot seem to find it's true path.
I don't know if this is a symbolic link, if it's using meta data, xml, json, etc...
I'm not sure if I need to update the icon cache.
And this is where I'm kind of starting to get a bit stumped. I've searched through forums, the Arch Wiki, other places, even tried to get suggestions reluctantly from MS-Copilot's:Chat-GTP 4...
VSCode, well Code-OSS to be more precise works just fine. Installing things works just fine. Most of the personalization so far is just fine.
One of the things that should be or ought to be the easiest, "simply changing a file's default icon to the icon you want", ended up becoming one of the most complicated processes of the entire installation, setup, configuration, and customization procedure.
Either love or hate Windows. I got to say, setting icons in Windows well at least Windows 7 and previous was much, easier. You just searched for the ico, png, etc. that you want to use select it within that icon's property sheet and you were done provided you didn't move or delete that image file. Here, within Linux, this is almost as bad as writing registry entries in Windows.
Everything else went smooth, but having to work around or within themes is really setting me back. Something that should take about a minute or two at the most, and I've been at this for several hours and now I'm just shaking my head!
Any kind of tips, suggestions, advice, pointers, etc. is very much appreciated. I'm just not sure what to do at this point, what to try next, where to go. I'm not a "Pro" in using Linux. I'm learning as I go, I'm experimenting, I'm testing, etc. I'm trying to learn the system. So please do not assume that I know a bunch of basic commands. I know enough to kind of navigate through the system, to install some stuff, but there are many things within Linux that I do not yet know. There are many tools that I do not yet know. This is why I choose to go with Arch Linux through a VM. If I break something, I can always start over! I also choose Arch not because it is easy, or hand holding such as Mint for those coming from other OSs, and no, I'm not trying to "mock or down grade Mint at all". It's a great Distro. I went with Arch because it has that DIY mentality and culture, and it's also the engineering personality that I tend to have. I do love a great challenge. Yet everyone has their moments and their limits.
